# How to reset to default backcolor in the picturebox using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I need your help. I have create a piano using pictureboxes in C#, Winforms. In the properties of pictureboxes i have set backcolor to a appropriate note(white and black notes).

And I created a combo box so i can select chords, like C chord, D chord ... On this link you can see the right notes for C chord.

[c chord for piano](http://www.read-and-play-piano.com/images/free-piano-chords-1.jpg)

When I select one chord(like C chord), the backcolor of a appropriate note changes to red, but then there is a problem when i select another chord in the combo box the previous chord that was selected stays red.

So my question is, is there anyway I can set back to default settings for backcolor or destroy previous behavior when I select something else in the combo box, or I need to use something else besides picturebox???

This is my code:

```
private void comboBox_selectNote_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox_selectNote.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: //C
                //RED
                pbC1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pbE1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pbG1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case 1: //C#
                //RED
                pbCsharp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pbF1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                pbGsharp1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
```

.....

Please i need your help, I already tried something but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @feralin it's winforms

Comment: ok. have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: @feralin do you mean I need to put the colors of the picture boxes in a array??

Comment: I'll update my answer to include some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must reassign the `BackColor` of the other `PictureBox`-es to the original color. You could, for example, create an array of `Color`s that store the original colors, and then copy those colors into the `PictureBox`-es that you want to reset. Some code:

```
// assumes you have NUM_KEYS piano keys / PictureBoxes
Color[] pianoKeyColors = new Color[NUM_KEYS];
// fill the pianoKeyColors array with the colors you want,
// perhaps alternating white-black-white- ...
// you may want to do that in the constructor for your Form

// you should also store the PictureBox-es in an array, so you can easily
// reference the one you want

private void comboBox_selectNote_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // reset all PictureBox-es to the original colors
    for (int key = 0; key < NUM_KEYS; key++)
        pianoKeys[key].BackColor = pianoKeyColors[key];
    // and then only set the BackColor to Red of keys in the chord
    switch (comboBox_selectNode.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: // C chord
            pianoKeys[KEY_C1].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pianoKeys[KEY_E1].BackColor = Color.Red;
            pianoKeys[KEY_G1].BackColor = Color.Red
            break;
        ... and the other cases ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you...I have learned and worked in C# but I forgot it little bit :)